# Prove that consecutive Legendre Polynomials do not have a common root.

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

I am using the following definition of Legendre Polynomials:

$P_0(x)=1$

$P_1(x)=x$

$\displaystyle P_{k+1}(x)=\frac{2k+1}{k+1}x P_k(x)-\frac{k}{k+1} P_{k-1}(x)$

Q: Prove that for no $k\in \mathbb{N}$ can $P_{k}(x)$ and $P_{k+1}(x)$ have any common root.

I have tried applying division algorithm for $P_{k+1}(x)$ and $P_{k}(x)$ *(divided by $P_{k}(x)$ and $P_{k-1}(x)$ respectively)* in order to conclude that the remainder will never be 0, but am not sure how to make this deduction.

Am I supposed to prove by induction? I personally don't see how to inductively prove this though.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You argue downwards, not upwards.

If $P_{k+1}$ and $P_k$
have a common root,
then this is also a root of $P_{k-1}$.
Continuing down,
this is also a root of $P_1$.
But the only root of $P_1$ is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Suppose that $P_k$ has some root $z$. Then $P_k(z)=0$. What does this imply about $P_{k+1}(z)$? (If you can answer this, you can probably figure out where the induction comes in.)